The method for adding a trigger for a job does not work when the application starts. Quartz .NET
When the application starts, I configure the job and trigger using IConfigureOptions. I use .AddJob and .AddTrigger In method Configure(QuartzOptions options). On the local stand everything starts correctly. An error occurs on the test stand: "SchedulerException: A new job defined without any triggers must be durable: DEFAULT.BackgroundJobTemporarily".
Version used:
<PackageReference Include="Quartz" Version="3.13.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Quartz.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.13.0" />

Program.cs setting:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddQuartz();
builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(opt =>
{
    opt.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});

builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefusedSetup>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IBackgroundProcessSettingRepository, BackgroundProcessSettingRepository>();

BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefusedSetup.cs:
public class BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefusedSetup(
    IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) : IConfigureOptions<QuartzOptions>
{
    public async void Configure(QuartzOptions options)
    {
        var jobKeyTemporarilyRefused = BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefused.Key;

        using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var backgroundProcessSettingRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBackgroundProcessSettingRepository>();
        var backgroundProcessSettingExists = await backgroundProcessSettingRepository.Exists(jobKeyTemporarilyRefused.Name);
        if (!backgroundProcessSettingExists)
            throw new Exception($"Can`t find setting with JobKeyName = {jobKeyTemporarilyRefused.Name}");
        // Get cron expression from DB
        var backgroundProcessSetting = await backgroundProcessSettingRepository
            .GetBackgroundProcessSettingAppModelByJobKeyName(jobKeyTemporarilyRefused.Name);

        options
            .AddJob<BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefused>(jobBuilder => jobBuilder.WithIdentity(jobKeyTemporarilyRefused))
            .AddTrigger(trigger =>
                trigger
                    .ForJob(jobKeyTemporarilyRefused)
                    .WithCronSchedule(backgroundProcessSetting.CronScheduleString,
                        x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()));
    }
}

BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefused.cs:
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefused(
    IUserTemporarilyRefusedFromMeetingHandleService userTemporarilyRefusedFromMeetingHandleService,
    ILogger<BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefused> logger) : IJob
{
    public static readonly JobKey Key = JobKey.Create(nameof(BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefused));
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await userTemporarilyRefusedFromMeetingHandleService.UserTemporarilyRefusedFromMeetingHandle();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.CustomError(e);
        }
    }
}

When the application on the test bench is launched, an error occurs: "SchedulerException: A new job defined without any triggers must be durable: DEFAULT.BackgroundJobTemporarilyRefused".
The cron-expression from the DB is obtained correctly.
Why the trigger is not added correctly? Help please.
I tried adding a group for triggers:
.WithIdentity("Trigger", "TestGroup")
I tried different flag in Program.cs:
opt.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
opt.AwaitApplicationStarted = true;

No result. Please help. What am I doing wrong?
